# Drive 50 SPI oled displays with a single ESP32

Tags: circuit-design, spi, oled

i need for a logistics project to use *A LOT* of Oled Displays in the mezzanine warehouse to show some details about the items.

Now, i want to use this base hardware and build around them the needed electronics in order to make everything work, so, i have:

- 1x ESP32
- 50x 74x40 dot matrix SPI oled display

At this moment, don't care about the power consumption, i need some advices in order to manage the logic of the SPI bus and the relative CS of the 50 displays.

What are your recommendations? keep in mind that i want to use a single CAT6 cable and his estimated lenght is about 10/15 meters.

Comment: My first recommendation would be: don't use 50 displays and one microcontroller.  When it breaks or needs any maintenance, the whole thing will be down.  Consider perhaps 8 displays per controller, then you have modularity and build more when, inevitably, needs change or something breaks.

Comment: Thanks @jonathanjo, actually i've considered this drawback in case of maintenance or problem

Comment: @VirtApp, why don't you use regular AC switches to switch the power to the AC adapters driving the LED strips?  Why does this need a microcontroller at all?

Comment: So, no one is able to give me an advice?